# Egyptian fractions similar to Erdos-Straus conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, unit-fractions

It is known that the Erdos-Straus conjecture is about writing $4/n$ as three unit fractions.
My question is whether it is known that if $a>4$
$$
\frac an=\frac1{x_1}+\frac1{x_2}+\cdots+\frac1{x_k}
$$
where $k<a$? Or it is a conjecture similar to Erdos-Straus one with the same hardness? For instance, is it known whether
$$
\frac 5n=\frac1{x_1}+\frac1{x_2}+\frac1{x_3}+\frac1{x_4} ?
$$

Comment: This is an open problem, as Elsholtz comments in http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2001-353-08/S0002-9947-01-02782-9/S0002-9947-01-02782-9.pdf (see the second para of the second page of the article).

Comment: Can be reduced to 3 term. And then use this formula.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erdös-straus-conjecture/831870#831870

Comment: See also D11 in Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, 3rd edition.

Comment: Decomposition into fractions $$\frac{5}{n}=\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3}+\frac{1}{x_4}$$ Always possible - because can take. $x_4=n$ Which leads to the well-known formula.

Comment: For the case of $\frac{5}{n}$ see [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56909/sierpinskis-conjecture](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56909/sierpinskis-conjecture).

Answer (score 2):

There is a conjecture for  5/n identical to the Erdos-Straus conjecture
and even for k/n, k any positive integer, see the Wikipedia article on the Erdos-Straus conjecture for details. Frank Okoh

Answer (score 0):

This is a very partial answer. If $n$ is a [practical number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number), then for every $a<n$ there is a reduction of $a/n$ as
$$\frac an=\frac1{x_1}+\dots\frac1{x_k}$$
with $k<a$.